# Limiting child process's memory usage with rlimit without affecting current process

Tags: go, system-calls, setrlimit

I want to limit the memory usage of a child process using rlimit. Currently our code is as follows:

```
old_rlimit := get_rlimit()
set_rlimit(child_process_rlimit)
cmd.Start()
set_rlimit(old_rlimit)
cmd.Wait()
```

However, sometimes Golang runtime will report out of memory error at `cmd.Start()`. It seems that in `cmd.Start()` current process will allocate some memory, and if current memory usage is higher than `child_process_rlimit`, an error will be raised.

I want to know is there any way to limit the memory usage of child process without affecting current one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `rlimit` to the child process only rather than relying on rlimit inheritance. Your main blocker here is clearly spelled out in the `setrlimit` man page:

> an unprivileged process may set only its soft limit to a value in the
>   range from 0 up to the hard limit, and (irreversibly) lower its hard
>   limit

The standard way to do this is through fork/exec, something along the lines of:

```
child_pid := fork()
if pid != 0 {
  // in child process
  setrlimit(...)
  execve(...)
}
```

If you don't want to do that, you still have a few options:

- run as privileged user
- `cmd.Run` a small wrapper (eg: `bash ulimit -m ...`) that calls the child process. note: `-m` is not honored by many systems.
- call `prlimit` (linux-specific and no syscall wrapper. [see this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/_8_os7mIs2M) for details)

Comment: What if the address space of the new rlimit is lower than current usage? Will the subsequent `execve` fail in this case?

Comment: Depending on which limit you're setting, you may get killed first, or `execve` may fail. Also be aware that I have no idea what is necessary to run `fork/exec` manually in Go (you may want to dig through the `os/exec` code.